# Large width of UILabel Cause memory issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, memory-management, uilabel

I want some marquee label type control in my application. I have created it but the problem is as below:

1.I have setup the scrollview first and then in that scrollview i have added `UILabel` with large text around 7000 character.and i am shifting content offset of the `UIScrollView` to make a text scrolling.

Now when allocating label, i make the width of the label according to the stringsize width like below:

```
UIFont *font = autoScrollLabel.font;

CGSize stringSize = [str1 sizeWithFont:font];

float width = stringSize.width;
```

and i give this width (its around 250000) to the `UILabel` width Like below:

```
autoScrollLabel.frame = CGRectMake(15,25,width,98);
```

=====

Now the problem is if i am allocating this width to `UILabel` with then it occupy around 300MB size of the application and at some instant it crashed the application due to memory issue.

Can anyone had ever faced this issue then please help on how to solve this memory issue or anyone who have any idea please put you suggestion.

**I have also other functionality like play, pause, scroll text with animation, and move the text offset according to the UISlider and start it from there.**

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A `UILabel` will render all the text at once event if it is off the screen. This is what is causing your memory issue.

<s>As an alternative, could you use a `UITextView` in your code to achieve the same functionality?</s>

`UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView` so you can set the textview's frame to bounds of the superview but adjust the `contentSize` property to `stringSize`

Edit: Sorry, the above wouldn't work as you cannot control the way the UITextView renders its text.

How about trying this: https://github.com/cbpowell/MarqueeLabel

Comment: But i want all the text in one line is this possible with UITextView?

Comment: You're right.. the above wouldn't work as you can't control how the text view will position the internal text. Sorry.

Comment: And if i suppose make it one line then i need to pass same width to UITextView as UILabel then this will not create much different, am i right?

Comment: Yeah, that won't make a difference. Check out my update

Comment: i have started with this class but i need one functionality like if i move the slider the text should shift and and if i start again then the text should start from there. In this class i can not shift content of the text because this class uses the animation to shift content so can not get what is the offset of the text when pause it, you got my point?